# Blender Internal. Edge post processing showing as see though

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I've been having an issue with a few models I've been working on that include the edge post processing option turned on.

[image]

For some reason some edges can be seen through certain polys. [image]

As you can see on the head of this model you can see the edging that is suppose to be on the other side. I've tried inverting the faces, deleting the faces and re-creating them but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other option anyone knows besides re-creating that entire section of the mesh?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: by "edge post processing" do you mean freestyle ? if it is you should post the line sets you are using

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. I added a picture in the original post showing what setting I'm using.

Comment: can you upload your blend file? i tried many things and i couldn't have this issue , you can upload the blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Yeah, just added it to the post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the materials "berry" and "iris" have transparency on,i think that's why

Comment: Holy cow, thank you so much!! I'm not sure how those got turned on but thank you for pointing that out. You're the best!

Comment: @root please write an answer to move this out of the unanswered list....

Answer (score 1):

The reason the edges on the back are outlined is because some pieces of the mesh in front are assigned to transparent materials.